# Bounding areas and restrictions for geolocalizing

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I'm trying to restraint an area to verify that certain points are correctly geolocalized. I have .klm files with the boundaries of the areas and also the coordinates of the points I'm trying to verify. I wonder If there is a way to combine this in code in a way the code itself identifies which points are inside the poligon and which aren't.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you've done. Some code.

Comment: I haven't really code anything. I have worked with rectangular areas before so what I usually do is stablish restrictions according to the boundary box and include or exclude the coordinates according to this limits. However now the limits have to be really specific, the boundaries of a city,  so I need to know if there's a way this could be done in any language or some suggestions to work with the information I already have.

Comment: And what is the `zipcode`tag for?

Comment: Because I thought of restricting this with the zipcode regions and the coordinates. I also have the poligons for those areas in my country, but I've read in other questions here that those are not areas so I'm a little confused about that now.